# Mass video metadata dump`

Tags: windows-7, video, metadata

I have a directory with 1000's of video files and I would like to collect some of the metadata for the files to run some analysis. I found that Windows 7 explorer can output the info but I have no way to bulk copy the info to a text (or other format) file. Here is a list of columns I would like in a dump:

File name,
Date modified,
Type,
Size,
Bit rate,
Frame height,
Frame width,
Frame rate

I have seen many tools that will dump the file listing of a directory to a file but nothing I have seen can dump the video specific info I need.

The solution can be a command line tool, a freeware or demo application, or VBA script. It doesn't even need to be automatic - I only have to do the procedure a few times. I am running Windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

[Media Info can do it.](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en)

Use the File > Open > Folder function of MediaInfo to load all the files, once it is done loading, use the File > Export function where you will find different formats to export to.